# does cgminer re-calculate every nonce from ASIC?

Tags: cgminer, mining-setup

i'm running a huge bunch of block erupter on my old computer, and the cpu time is too high to add more usb dongle miners, so i wonder if cgminer is recalculating the insufficient diff nonces and wasted my precious cpu time on my old computer.

anyone familiar with cgminer of bfgminer could help me with this 'stupid' question, thanks.

Comment: Are you mining solo or in a pool? (Short answer: Your CPU must be able to do one hash per second for every 13 block erupters you have, approximately.)

Comment: running on pool. my problem is if insufficient diff nonce is recalculated by CPU? i guess not, but need insurance.